# Assembly sarl and idivl - interpreting

Tags: assembly, sar

I've a problem understanding the following Assembly Code. It would be great if you could just give me an example with numbers how this looks like behind the scenes.

```
movl $0, %ecx
movl $0, %eax
addl $1, %eax
movl %eax, %edx
sarl $31, %edx
idivl $7
movl %edx, %eax
movl (%esp, %eax, 4), %eax
movl %eax, (%esp, %ecx, 4)
```

I think I may misinterpret the sarl and idivl because my result makes no sense..

Thanks a lot for your help!! I've been sitting in front of that code for 3 hours now^^

I think:

ecx = 0

eax = 0

eax = 0 + 1 = 1

edx = eax = 1

now shifting edx => edx = 0

now edx:eax is divided by 7?

why can't I just set edx = 0 and leave sarl out? wouldn't that be the same?

Comment: Edit your question adding what you have figured out. Also, you can use a debugger to single step it with any number you like.

Comment: `idivl $7`? Does this even assemble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why can't I just set `edx` = 0 and leave `sarl` out? wouldn't that be the same?

Not for a signed division, which is what `idiv` is. These two instructions are simulating what the `CDQ` instruction does:

```
movl %eax, %edx
sarl $31, %edx
```

That is,

> "`SAR` preserves the sign of the source operand by clearing empty bit positions if the operand is positive and setting the empty bits if the operand is negative."

and

> "The `CDQ` instruction copies the sign (bit 31) of the doubleword in the `EAX` register into every bit position in the `EDX` register. The `CDQ` instruction can be used to produce a quadword dividend from a doubleword before doubleword division."

Note that `sarl` updates some of the status flags, while `cdq` doesn't, so `movl` + `sarl` won't be exactly the same as `cdq`. It's not clear from the question why the code doesn't simply use `cdq`.